# How can I inherit from a Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created a page to be the base `Page` in my web application to add inside it some common functionality. but when I try to inhirite from it then VS gives me the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'CentralPage' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Note: I just want code-behind functionality in the base page.

What should I do ?

Comment: Maybe posting the code-behind of your page would be useful.

Answer (score 5):

You need your base page to inherit from page. From your comment, I've put the two in different namespaces, maybe that will help you:

```
namespace Project.BasePages
{
    public class BasePage : Page
    {
    }
}
```

then all other pages should inherit from `BasePage` instead of the default `Page`:

```
using Project.BasePages;

namespace Project.ContentPages
{
    public partial class Page1 : BasePage
    {
    }
}
```

or

```
namespace Project.ContentPages
{
    public partial class Page1 : Project.BasePages.BasePage
    {
    }
}
```

Note that `BasePage` shouldn't be a full ASPX page, just a normal `*.cs` class file.

Comment: Thanks, I know that but when BasePage exists in a another file, I couldn't use what you wrote.

Comment: @John: it's perfectly normal for the two classes to be in separate files. If they're in the same project and in the same namespace, they should be able to "see" each other fine. If `BasePage` is in a different namespace to `Page1`, you'll need to have a `using` statement at the top of the file to include the correct namespace.

Comment: @Graham Clark: but seems there's no namespace!! and I couldn't access to the base page through `base::` !!!

Comment: @John: it's generally easier to partition your classes into namespaces; using C# in Visual Studio will always wrap a class inside a namespace. If no namespace is defined in the code file, I'm pretty sure it will just default to the namespace of the project it's in. So 2 classes in the same project without namespaces in their code files should be able to "see" each other.

Comment: @John: you don't want to be doing `base::`, to access a method of a base class from a child class, you just do `base.methodName()`.

Comment: @– Graham Clark: first, I solved my problem by moving the base page into the AppCode folder, there.. all pages can access to it.

Comment: @– Graham Clark: "So 2 classes in the same project without namespaces in their code files should be able to "see" each other": seems no, if the two classes inside two pages files. try it please.

Answer (score 0):

i guess u should use master pages for common functionality. anyways is the Central page in the same namespace as the one you are inherenting. try using fully qualified name or the using directive.

Comment: Sorry, how to get [fully qualified name] ?

Comment: @John: a fully qualified name is the full namespace of the class plus its name, e.g. `var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder()`. If you have a using statement `using System.Text;` at the top of a file, you can then just type `var sb = new StringBuilder()`.